# Billable time for audio to text conversion

Tags: google-cloud-speech

We are using "google-cloud/speech" npm to covert audio files to text.

The API returned "totalBilledTime" as 15 seconds for a audio with duration of 4 seconds.

If we convert two 4 seconds audio files the "totalBilledTime" for these two audio files will be 15 seconds each.

Are you considering "30 seconds" as the billable time for these two 4 seconds audio file?

Comment: If you find my answer helpful for your question, please consider to accept/upvote it as per [stackoverflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the billable time for your case will be 30 seconds. The [pricing page](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/pricing#pricing_calculations) for Cloud Speech-to-Text  states that each request is rounded up to the nearest increment of 15 seconds. For example, if you make three distinct requests, each containing 7 seconds of audio, you are billed for 45 seconds (3 × 15 seconds) of audio.